# open google doc in web view in OS 4.1 in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I am working on app in which I need to open a pdf in a google doc with the help of a URL provided. I am using Web view for this. its working fine on all OS like 2.2., that I have tested but its not working on Android OS 4.1 device of my client.

```
if(NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(ShowPdfInWebView.this))
        {
            WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf_webview);

            String pdfURL=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("PDFURL");
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);


        }
```

I am using this code.

Please let me know, if it requires some different logic's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice trick to do that... you can use google docs to open your pdf in a WebView:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://yoururl.com/yourpdf.pdf");
```

Comment: You have javascript enabled for your webview?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full guide to do it:

http://weimenglee.blogspot.dk/2013/05/android-tip-displaying-pdf-document.html